# Check for list of substrings inside string column in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

For checking if a **single** string is contained in rows of one column. (for example, `"abc"` is contained in `"abcdef"`), the following code is useful:

```
df_filtered = df.filter(df.columnName.contains('abc'))
```

The result would be for example `"_wordabc","thisabce","2abc1"`.

How can I check for **multiple** strings (for example `['ab1','cd2','ef3']`) at the same time?

I'm ideally searching for something like this:

```
df_filtered = df.filter(df.columnName.contains(['word1','word2','word3']))
```

The result would be for example `"x_ab1","_cd2_","abef3"`.

*Please, post scalable solutions (no for loops, for example) because the aim is to check a big list around 1000 elements.*

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `isin`

```
df_filtered = df.filter(df['columnName'].isin('word1','word2','word3')
```

> Edit

You need `rlike` function to achieve your result

```
words="(aaa|bbb|ccc)"

df.filter(df['columnName'].rlike(words))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm aiming for. I'll clarify my question because i meant "contains" not "equal".

Comment: @Manrique Please check edit part now